# É possível monitorar todas as Responses e Headers da página para usar como gatilho de uma função?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5, xmlhttprequest

Tenho um script que precisa ser executado somente após o retorno de uma requisição da página, pois a requisição retorna conteúdo HTML, e a função que quero executar logo após, implementa esse HTML recebido. O problema é que não posso mexer nas outras funções pois meu acesso é limitado.

Já sei que essas requisições são feitas quando clico no link que na imagem chamei de "GATILHO", porém, as respostas não só chegam em tempos muito variados, como também mudam a ordem de retorno por ser assíncrono.

Só preciso reconhecer quando **1ª resposta** (do código que não posso mudar) vier pra mim, pra só então eu executar o meu script que traz a **2ª resposta**.

[image: Gatilho e tempo de resposta]

Minha solução temporária foi usar o *setTimeout()* para executar minha função *4 segundos* após o clique no link GATILHO (Meus cursos), porque pelos meus testes, mesmo com uma internet "razoável", dá tempo tempo de receber todas as requisições.

Abaixo eu mostro o cabeçalho da 1ª resposta.
Alguém teria alguma ideia do que eu poderia fazer?

[image: Cabeçalho]

Comment: Se entendi bem, você quer fazer um tipo de listener para verificar alguma mudança na página que tenha a ver com o retorno da 1ª resposta, é isso?

Comment: Exatamente. Procurei por exemplos mas... nada.

Comment: Por mais que esteja funcionando com o setTimout() é notada demora na execução da 2ª requisição, pois, por mais que a 1ª resposta chegue, a segunda está setada fixa pra só executar após 4 segundos, tempo o suficiente para os novos usuários pensarem que não está funcionando e acabar clicar de novo no _link_. Consegui ser claro, @DvD ?

Comment: Sim... depois que chama a segunda função da segunda resposta, o que acontece? a página será recarregada depois? Essa segunda função, mexe na mesma div da primeira?

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia usar o <s>`DOMSubtreeModified`</s>, porém, segundo [documentações](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), ele está sendo descontinuado e não seria recomendável usá-lo.

O que pode ser feito, como solução, é criar um `setInterval` que ficará verificando, após o tempo setado, quando um determinado elemento existir na página.

Como não sabemos ao certo os elementos da sua página (sua pergunta não fornece tais detalhes), o conceito abaixo funciona e deve ser adaptado de acordo ao seu código:

Vamos supor que eu tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<div>
   <div id="retorno">
      Texto etc...
   </div>
</div>
```

E o Ajax insere, como retorno da 1ª resposta, o seguinte código para dentro da `div` "retorno":

```
<div id="resposta1">
    Esta é a resposta 1
</div>
```

Após o Ajax, o HTML ficaria assim:

```
<div>
   <div id="retorno">
      <div id="resposta1">
         Esta é a resposta 1
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Com o script abaixo, usando `setInterval`, eu verificaria quando essa `div` "resposta1", retornada do Ajax, estaria presente na página (antes do Ajax ela não existia) e chamar a segunda função:

```
<script>
temporizador = setInterval(function(){
    if($("#resposta1")){
       clearInterval("temporizador"); // paro o setInterval
       // chamo a segunda função
    }
}, 1000); // de 1 em 1 segundo
</script>
```

Logo, para adaptar o "temporizador" no exemplo acima, você precisa saber qual `div` é inserida **apenas** e **exclusivamente** no retorno do Ajax da 1ª resposta.

Comment: Muito bom!!! Como a função que uso só é ativada após o click num link, não sobrecarregaria a página nesse seu método. Agora, eu não conhecia o _DOMSubtreeModified_ . Como você disse que esse método está sendo descontinuado, fui ler sobre, e isso me levou ao **MutationObserver**, e ele que passei a usar. Ele monitora se algum atributo na página é modificado. Atendeu certinho ao que eu queria! Obrigado @DvD !!!